# Logitech Mouse Appearing Incorrectly

Tags: mouse, logitech

```
[~  dave@daveX1 ]$ xinput                                                                                                                                rvm: 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech G500                             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech G500                             id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

xinput reveals that there are two mice.  Unplugging my mouse takes them both away.

Listing them with xinput reveals that one has 7 buttons, the other 24.  This would be why I can't use my back button, I reckon.

```
Logitech G500                               id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 6 classes:
        Class originated from: 14. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 7
```

And the other:

```
Logitech G500                               id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 7 classes:
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 24
```

I think my question is, how do i get rid of that first mouse, or make the second one the default?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the Logitech software profiles that were stored on the mouse were to blame.

For some reason, on a Windows PC and OSX, this mouse worked fine with the standard profile.  But when I plug it into my Ubuntu laptop, it defaulted to a weird profile that I made for gaming.
I deleted that profile, and now my mouse works.